# IntelliJ: what difference between "SBT Console" and "SBT Shell"?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, intellij-plugin

In the IntelliJ I see two tool windows: *SBT Console* and *SBT Shell*. What is the difference between these tools?

Comment: which version and what platform are you using?

Answer (score 6):

You may have installed both scala and sbt plugins. The newer version of scala plugin has sbt as part of it.

`sbt console` is the sbt plugin -- click start you will enter into sbt interactive mode.

`sbt shell` is part of the scala plugin, which is similar to the above mentioned `sbt console` and can autocomplete commands.

Here is a description: https://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2017/03/23/scala-plugin-for-intellij-idea-2017-1-cleaner-ui-sbt-shell-repl-worksheet-akka-support-and-more/

Answer (score 4):

[SBT Console plugin](https://github.com/orfjackal/idea-sbt-plugin) is deprecated in favour of [IntelliJ Scala Plugin](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-scala). Deprecation notice [states](https://github.com/orfjackal/idea-sbt-plugin#deprecation):

> JetBrains have recently [added support](https://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2017/03/23/scala-plugin-for-intellij-idea-2017-1-cleaner-ui-sbt-shell-repl-worksheet-akka-support-and-more/) for an SBT console to the
>   IntellIJ Scala Plugin. This is now the recommended way to use SBT
>   within IntellIJ. No new releases of this plugin are planned.